# Расчет рейтинга одной строкой

Tags: mysql

Рейтинг пользователя складывается из нескольких составляющих. Это как оценки его комментариев, его оценки других комментариев, так и оценки написанных им статей. Принцип, как в хешкоде. Конечно же, каждое составляющее по-разному влияет на его рейтинг (где-то +5, где-то +1, а где-то -1), и все данные находятся в разных таблицах. Каким образом можно посчитать его рейтинг одним запросам mysql?

Помогите, пожалуйста. Я обычно справлялся php. Но в этом случае мне кажется, что будет эффективнее все сделать mysql'ом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерный ответ я нашел.

- Посчитать отдельно каждое составляющее рейтинга

Это поможет сделать функции IF и SUM:

```
$rating_one = "
   SELECT 
    SUM(IF (liked = 1, 2, -1)) AS rating
   FROM 
    table_one
   WHERE 
    user_id = 1
";
```

Таких запросов можно сделать сразу несколько. Но чтобы результат обязательно записывался в столбец `rating` или какой либо другой с помощью `AS`

- Объединить эти запросы с помощью UNION

  ```
  $rating_sum = $rating_one.' UNION '.$rating_two.' UNION '.$rating_three;
  ```

Если сделать запрос с текстом, сохраненным в переменную `$rating_sum`,  сразу, то получим несколько значений в столбце rating, которые осталось только просуммировать.

- Опять же с помощью функции SUM получаем общее значение:

  ```
  $rating_query = "SELECT SUM(rating) AS rating FROM (".$rating_sum.") AS tmp_table";
  ```

Как обработать вероятный NULL на выходе я пока не знаю. Возможно, с помощью IF и ISNULL. Но единственный выход из ситуации, который я вижу, это заменить SUM(rating) на:

```
IF(ISNULL(SUM(rating)), 0, SUM(rating))
```

Либо строить еще один этаж SELECT'a:

```
$rating_query = "SELECT IF(ISNULL(rating), 0, rating) AS rating FROM (".$rating_query.") AS tmp_table"
```

Я не знаю, как работает mysql: то ли он при каждом обращении SUM(rating) заново все просчитывает, либо понимает, что это дело уже было, и берет значение от туда -- поэтому не готов сказать, который из этих двух вариантов будет лучше.

Comment: > На сайте планируется частое удаление контента. 

рейтинг будет скакать или это вас не беспокоит?  

ЗЫ `IF(ISNULL(rating), 0, rating)` можно заменить на `IFNULL(rating,0)`  
ЗЗЫ на хэшкоде ведется история, посмотреть (часть) ее можно в профиле там и изменение кармы и кто и что сделал, это логичный путь и не слишком сложный, зря вы упорствуете.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, будет скакать и очень сильно. И это очень сильно влияет на возможности пользователя.

Comment: @oliverfoxi, это все к тому, что принцип у вас не "как на хэшкоде". старайтесь в следующий раз более четко описывать задачу.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, вроде стараюсь... Спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 2):

Если различные составляющие рейтинга не влияют друг на друга каким-то хитрым способом, а просто суммируются, то можно хранить уже посчитанный рейтинг и увеличивать/уменьшать его при каких-то событиях. И опционально отдельно хранить историю таких событий.

Comment: Не хочу так. На сайте планируется частое удаление контента. Выследить все эти события можно, но "не хочу"..)

Comment: +1. @oliverfoxi, в вашем варианте рейтинг будет скакать при удалениях в обратную сторону. а без рассчитанного значения слишком долго будут данные собираться из разных источников. представьте, что вам нужно вывести список участников с их рейтингом.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, списка как такового не будет. Рейтинг нужен для других целей.

Comment: Если речь идёт о чём-то вроде кармы, как здесь и на всяких там хабрах, то-есть о каком-то важном и часто востребованном атрибуте, то логичнее кажется всё-таки хранить её в готовом виде (и хранить все события изменения кармы). В таком случае «все эти события» должны быть выловленны, учтены и причёсан, отсутствие этого грозит геморроем в будущем.

Если это какая-то внутренняя метрика (выводимая из ряда других метрик), которая нужна например для аналитики, то можно и на ходу считать.